# Sending email using mailgun PHP API

Tags: php, email, guzzle, mailgun

I am trying to send an email with mailguns PHP api:

```
define('MAILGUN_KEY', 'key-ExamPle3xAMPle');
define('MAILGUN_DOMAIN', 'example.com');

$mailgun = new Mailgun\Mailgun(MAILGUN_KEY);

$mailgun->sendMessage(MAILGUN_DOMAIN, [
                'from'      => 'noreply@signstoptt.com',
                'to'        => $email,
                'subject'   => 'Sign Stop mailing list confirmation.',
                'html'      => "
                    Hello{$name},</br></br>
                    This is a test." 
            ]);
```

I have even tried to use array() instead of [ ].

I receive the following error in my php error log:

MissingRequiredParameters

It implies that what I am passing to the post function is incomplete or incorrect. upon inspecting the post function in the RestClient, I see that the function requires 2 arrays and not 1, so I tried adding a 2nd array with message attachments and it just got more errors, this time with guzzle (a dependency for mailgun)

```
[26-Jan-2015 14:32:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\MissingRequiredParameters' with message 'The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs!' in C:\Users\Zachary\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SS_MailingList\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php:187
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\Users\Zachary\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SS_MailingList\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php(116): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->responseHandler(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response))
    #1 C:\Users\Zachary\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SS_MailingList\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Mailgun.php(106): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->post('signstoptt.com/...', Array, Array)
    #2 C:\Users\Zachary\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SS_MailingList\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Mailgun.php(53): Mailgun\Mailgun->post('signstoptt.com/...', Array, Array)
    #3 C:\Users\Zachary\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SS_MailingList\subscribe.php(26): Mailgun\Mailgun->sendMessage('signstoptt.com', Array)
    #4 in C:\Users\Zachary\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SS_MailingList\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php on line 187
```

Has anyone else had this problem. I am running the site on a glassfish server setup by netbeans. I also used composer to install mailgun and its dependencies.

EDIT: Added more information.

init.php

```
<?php

    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    define('MAILGUN_KEY', 'key-854743a7e');
    define('MAILGUN_PUBKEY', 'pubkey-b00e47d7');

    define('MAILGUN_DOMAIN', 'example.com');
    define('MAILGUN_LIST', 'customers@example.com');
    define('MAILGUN_SECRET','xjhbJH7');

    $mailgun = new Mailgun\Mailgun(MAILGUN_KEY);

    $mailgunValidate = new Mailgun\Mailgun(MAILGUN_PUBKEY);

    $mailgunOptIn = $mailgun->OptInHandler();
```

subscribe.php

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $validate = $mailgunValidate->get('address/validate', [
            'address' => $email
        ])->http_response_body;

    if($validate->is_valid)
        {
            $hash = $mailgunOptIn->generateHash(MAILGUN_LIST, MAILGUN_SECRET, $email);

            $result = $mailgun->sendMessage(MAILGUN_DOMAIN, [
                'from'      => 'noreply@example.com',
                'to'        => $email,
                'subject'   => 'example mailing list confirmation.',
                'html'      => "
                    Hello{$name},</br></br>
                    You submitted a request to join our mailing list, to confirm this subscription please click on the link provided below.</br></br>
                    http://localhost:8000/confirm.php?hash={$hash}" 
            ]);


            $mailgun->post('lists/' . MAILGUN_LIST . '/members', [
                'name'          => $name,
                'address'       => $email,
                'subscribed'    => 'no'
            ]);

            header('Location: ./');

        }
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Subscribe | Mailing list</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="subscribe.php" method="post">
                <div class="field">
                    <label>
                        Name
                        <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>
                        Email
                        <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="button">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure  `$email` contain a valid email address?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I'll hardcode it to make sure now. Edit: I manually put an email and same thing. For the record the info comes from a form, and is validated by the mailgun api, and that works. Just doing anything else seems to not.

Comment: Well, from what I've been able to work out the error you're seeing is because Mailgun is returning a 400 response code, which means they didn't get the inputs they were expecting for the request. I'm reasonably confident it's not an error in the `RestClient` it's self though. However, someone with more Mailgun experience than me will need to help further I'm afraid.

Comment: @matiszac is your code inside a closure or just directly in a PHP class? Can you post maybe the function it is enclosed in?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata I have edited my post and added everything. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue but its solved for me now. We need to following code to send the email from mailgun
First, you need to create an instance of the Mailgun class using your API key:

```
$mg = Mailgun::create('YourAPIKEY'); // the key will be containing the work key in it (ie: key-123456789)
```

Then, use the created instance to send an email:

```
$mg->messages()->send($domain, [
                'from'    => $from,
                'to'      => $email,
                'subject' => $subject,
                'sender' => $sender,
            'html' => $html
        ]);
```

The above code will work for domain located in US. However, if you are using a Mailgun domain located in the EU, you should modify the create function as follows:

```
$mg = Mailgun::create('YourAPIKEY','https://api.eu.mailgun.net');
```

Feel free to customize this version of the answer according to your preferences.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the `text` key which is used when `html` isn't available by the mail client.

Your code will look like

```
define('MAILGUN_KEY', 'key-ExamPle3xAMPle');
define('MAILGUN_DOMAIN', 'example.com');

$mailgun = new Mailgun\Mailgun(MAILGUN_KEY);

$mailgun->sendMessage(MAILGUN_DOMAIN, [
                'from'      => 'noreply@signstoptt.com',
                'to'        => $email,
                'subject'   => 'Sign Stop mailing list confirmation.',
                'text'      => 'Hello ' . $name . ', this is a test.',
                'html'      => '
                    Hello ' . $name . ',</br></br>
                    This is a test.'
            ]);
```

By the way; I recommend always using single quotes or double quotes for readability.

Comment: @mightyspaj Do you have the latest version of the Mailgun API (1.8)? this one should give a better description of the error. (If you got the `The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs!` problem)